# Dynamically URL navigation between mattabs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an application which looks like on the image below.I used mattabs inside nav links.

```
 this.navLinks = [
      {
          label: 'Preview',
          link:  './1',
          index: 0
      }, {
          label: 'Tuning',
          link: './tabtest2',
          index: 1
      }, {
          label: 'Payment',
          link: './tabtest3',
          index: 2
      }, 
  ];
```

in this code part when I press preview it shows me the 2nd element on the list(array).Thats exactly how I want it to work but it should be controlled dynamically.I made string concatanation and changed with that link on the preview tab but URL isnt recognizable.My concatanation is exactly same like '.1' on the link property
Here's what I tried below

**TS File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from './car.model';
import { CarService } from './car.sevice';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: './cars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cars.component.css']
})
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks: any[];
  public href: string = "";
  activeLinkIndex = -1;
  mySubject;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
        this.activeLinkIndex = this.navLinks.indexOf(this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));
    });
    this.mySubject=this.carService.carrierSubject.subscribe(value=>
      {
        this.id=value;
        let numid=this.id.toString();
        this.newString="./".concat(numid);
        console.log(this.newString);
      })
  }
  newString:string='';
  id:number;
  car:Car;
  constructor(private carService:CarService,private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {
    this.navLinks = [
      {
          label: 'Preview',
          link:  '.1',
          index: 0
      }, {
          label: 'Tuning',
          link: './tabtest2',
          index: 1
      }, {
          label: 'Payment',
          link: './tabtest3',
          index: 2
      }, 
  ];
   }

  onTuning()
  {
    this.router.navigate(['tuning'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }  
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <app-car-list></app-car-list>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
                <a mat-tab-link
                *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                [routerLink]="link.link"
                routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
                [active]="rla.isActive">
               {{link.label}}
              </a>
              </nav>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>     
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]